# VS2010 Extension like Smart Paster?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Alex Papadimoulis' [Smart Paster](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2004/05/25/Smart-Paster-1.1-Add-In---StringBuilder-and-Better-C_2300_-Handling.aspx) is a great little tool that can paste text in programmer-friendly ways (e.g. as a StringBuilder, as a language-specific string literal, etc.).  However, it doesn't seem to be available for VS2010.

Anyone know of a similar extension or of plans to port Smart Paster?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882874/smart-paster-add-in-for-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, though I doubt there would be much, if any, work in updating it for VS2010.  The command system is essentially unchanged.  It looks like Alex has source available, so you could try just downloading the VS2008 source and rebuilding.

Updating the extension may result in a simpler source in terms of package management (`VSIX` files) and the new `.pkgdef` files (for editing the registry), but what's there may just work to a significant degree without any changes.

Answer (score 2):

Posted [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?mzyjamytnlq). I've modified slightly the one here (it didn't compile as it was): www.martinwilley.com/blog/2010/06/06/SmartPasteIn2010.aspx