# Smart Paster Add-In for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, add-in

Does anyone know of any free add-in similar to **Smart Paster**, but for Visual Studio 2010?
Unfortunately, Smart Paster only works for VS2005 and VS2008.

For the ones that don't know what I'm talking about, [check it out](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2004/05/25/Smart-Paster-1.1-Add-In---StringBuilder-and-Better-C_2300_-Handling.aspx).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My simplified (C# only) version for 2010 is [here](http://martinwilley.com/blog/2010/06/06/SmartPasteIn2010.aspx)
The post explains the VS2010 incompatibility (CommandBarButton.FaceId throws an exception) so you can change the VS2008 source code if you want.
Update: full source and binary are now in [Codeplex](http://smartpaster2010.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Althought martins code works i had to remove the following flag from devenv.config (which i had added before) <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/> With this flag enabled it does not work

Comment: Very nice add-in. I'm wondering how it could be possible to link a keyboard shortcut to any of the actions available in this add-in. When I try to execute some action with keyboard shortcut, I received a message that telling me that the add-in supporting this command cannot be loaded. Have you any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Working code for the addin for Visual Studio 2010 can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/smartpaster/source/checkout

I found that link via this page: http://inedo.com/downloads/smartpaster

However, the zip on that page is for a version that is not compatible with 2010. But get the code from Google code. That works.

Comment: Very very nice tool! I add a new feature on my side to copy a string from code to remove automatically the quotes to be able to copy it back to sql management studio. With that tool, I'm now able to switch back and forth from my visual studio to sql management studio.

Comment: Samuel, that sounds great. Any chance that you might share your work?